# define ('Disallow_File_Edit', true ) is not working in WordPress 4.0

Tags: wordpress, security

I have put the follwoing code in `wp-config.php` for disabling the file edit through Admin user. 
But still Admin user can edit the functions through web url : `wp-login.php`.

```
define ('Disallow_File_Edit', true  )
```

in WordPress.

Comment: It's not clear how the `wp-login.php` file is related to the question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Is the problem still unsolved?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that WordPress uses the `DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT` constant and not the `Disallow_File_Edit` constant.

You should therefore use:

```
define ('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true  );
```

Another option would be to allow the *case-insensitive* definition by using the *third* parameter of the `defined()` PHP function:

```
define ('Disallow_File_Edit', true, true );
```

Comment: I encounter the same problem. Adding the DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT constant does not help. PHP reaches $caps[] = 'do_not_allow'; line in wp-includes/capabilities.php (only place where the constant is used), but editing plugins and themes is still possible.

Comment: It works on my 4.1 install, I get `"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."` message when trying to access the file editor. Where did you place the line? @Avaer

Comment: I did not modify the code, that line comes from 4.1. Never mind. Turned out it was the Groups plugin's fault. When it's enabled, admin can do everything. I might report this as a bug. Thank you for your response.